# The final variable 'articleC' can't be read because it is potentially unassigned at this point

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm new to Flutter. And I get an error like this: The final variable 'articleC' can't be read because it is potentially unassigned at this point.

Here is where I use:

```
 Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (ctx) => DetailScreen(article: articleC)));
```

I have added an article class on the *detail page* as required. Here, when I call the detail class, it asks me for an article class, and I give it an article class. But I get an error as above.

I defined the article class as : `final Article articleC;`

Comment: Please share more code so that we can better help you.

Comment: you just declare your `final Article articleC;` but you need to assign `articleC`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share a little bit of code, it will be easier to trace. Also the error you've got could also be found in the [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#read_potentially_unassigned_final).

> ##### `read_potentially_unassigned_final`
>
> The final variable ‘{0}’ can’t be read because it’s potentially
> unassigned at this point.
>
> ##### **Description**
>
> The analyzer produces this diagnostic when a final local variable that
> isn’t initialized at the declaration site is
> read at a point where the compiler can’t prove that the variable is
> always initialized before it’s referenced.

There could be a possibility that your code read the variable `articleC` prior to being declared or initialized.

Check the example from the documentation for the possible solution:

> ##### **Example** The following code produces this diagnostic because the final local variable `x` is read (on line 3) when it’s possible
>
> that it hasn’t yet been initialized:
>
> ```
> int f() {
>   final int x;
>   return x;
> }
> ```
>
> ##### **Common fixes**
>
> Ensure that the variable has been initialized before it’s read:
>
> ```
> int f(bool b) {
>   final int x;
>   if (b) {
>     x = 0;
>   } else {
>     x = 1;
>   }
>   return x;
> }
> ```